# what does 'T', 'f', 'E', 'e', '→' stand for in dart/flutter docs?

Tags: dart, flutter

i`m learning the flutter, but i do not understand those letters meaning.

```
map<T>(T f(E e)) → Iterable<T>
Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by 
calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order. [...]
```

so,what do they stand for?
T:
f:
E:
e:
→:

Comment: T is the generic data type eg String, int or CustomModel etc. f is the function E is the new element returned by the function.

Comment: @Ayush Gupta   thank you very much!   what about e and →?

Comment: These are generic types.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`Iterable.map<T>`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html):

> ```
> map<T>(T f(E e)) → Iterable<T>
> ```
>
> Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by  calling
>   f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order. [...]

- `T` is a language `Type` in this case the Type of the items of the iterable and is also the type that function `f` must return.
- `→` tells you the `return type` of the whole function (`map`) in this case an `Iterable` of `T`
- `f` is the function applied to the `Element e` that is passed as the parameter to the function so that the function could do some operation with this current value and then return a new value of type `T` based on the value of the element `e`.

If you navigate the Iterable [`map` function definition](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) you will see that:

```
Iterable<T> map <T>(
    T f(
      E e
    )
)
```

So I wanna sharpen my answer starting with the exact `map<T>` function of the OP and then swich to a more complex example.

Just to clarify all these let's take a concrete class of the Iterable class, the [Set](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Set-class.html) class choosing a `Set` of type `String` in such a scenario:

```
Set<String> mySet = Set();
for (int i=0; i++<5;) {
  mySet.add(i.toString());
}
var myNewSet = mySet.map((currentValue) => (return "new" + currentValue));
for (var newValue in myNewSet) {
  debugPrint(newValue);
}
```

Here I've got a *Set of String* `Set<String>` and I want another *Set of String* `Set<String>` so that **the value is the same value of the original map, but sorrounded with a prefix of `"new:"`**. And for that we could easily use the `map<T>` along with the closure it wants as paraemters.

The function passed as closure is

```
(currentValue) => ("new:" + currentValue)
```

And if we want we could write it also like that:

```
(currentValue) {
  return "new:" + currentValue;
}
```

or even pass a function like that:

```
String modifySetElement(String currentValue) {
  return "new:" + currentValue;
}
```

- `var myNewSet = mySet.map((value) => ("new:" + value));`
- `var myNewSet = mySet.map((value) {return "new:" + value;});`
- `var myNewSet = mySet.map((value) => modifySetElement("new:" + value));`

And this means that the parameter of the function (closure) is the `String` **value** of the **element** `E` of the `Set` we're modifying.
We don't even have to specify the type because its inferred by method definition, that's one of the power of generics.

The function (closure) will be applied to all the Set's elements once at a time, but you write it once as a closure.

[image]

So summarising:

- `T` is String
- `E` is the element we are dealing with inside of the function
- `f` is our closure

Let's go deeper with a more complex example. We'll now deal with the [Dart Map](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map-class.html) class.

Its [`map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/map.html) function is define like that:

```
map<K2, V2>(MapEntry<K2, V2> f(K key, V value)) → Map<K2, V2>
```

So in this case the previous first and third `T` is `(K2, V2)` and the return type of the function `f` (closure), that takes as element `E` parameter the pair  `K` and `V` (that are the key and value of the current `MapEntry` element of the iteration), is a type of `MapEntry<K2, V2>` and is the previous second `T`.

The whole function then return a new  `Map<K2, V2>`

The following is an actual example with `Map`:

```
Map<int, String> myMap = Map();
for (int i=0; i++<5;) {
  myMap[i] = i.toString();
}
var myNewMap = myMap.map((key, value) => (MapEntry(key, "new:" + value)));
for (var mapNewEntry in myNewMap.entries) {
  debugPrint(mapNewEntry.value);
}
```

In this example I've got a `Map<int, String>` and I want another `Map<int, String>` so that (like before) **the value is the same value of the original map, but sorrounded with a prefix of `"new:"`**.

[image]

Again you could write the closure (your `f` function) also in this way (maybe it highlights better the fact that it's a fanction that create a brand new MapEntry based on the current map entry value).

```
var myNewMap = myMap.map((key, value) {
    String newString = "new:" + value;
    return MapEntry(key, newString);
});
```

All these symbols are called [*Generics*](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics) because they are generic placeholder that correspond to a type or another based on the context you are using them.

That's an extract from the above link:

> **Using generic methods**
>
> Initially, Dart’s generic support was limited to classes. A newer syntax, called generic methods, allows
>   type arguments on methods and functions:
>
> ```
> T first<T>(List<T> ts) {
>   // Do some initial work or error checking, then...
>   T tmp = ts[0];
>   // Do some additional checking or processing...
>   return tmp;
> }
> ```
>
> Here the generic type parameter on first () allows you to use the
>   type argument T in several places:
>
> In the function’s return type (`T`). In the type of an argument
>   (`List<T>`). In the type of a local variable (`T tmp`).

**Follow this [link](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-follow-existing-mnemonic-conventions-when-naming-type-parameters) for Generics name conventions.**

Comment: Thank you very very very much! All of your answer are what i want to know, and must to know.

Comment: Do you have a blog to follow? maybe github? I want to follow you .

Comment: @bill.Feng Hi! That makes me really happy. I've got a blog but nowadays I've no time to publish my own posts 'cause when I've got some spare time I come here on SO. Btw, thanks. Really appreciate that.