# What does <T> mean in flutter?

Tags: flutter, types

So I was going through some flutter packages and I saw T being used as a type. Just wondering what that means, like is that a data type or something else?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894436/what-does-t-f-e-e-%E2%86%92-stand-for-in-dart-flutter-docs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does 'T', 'f', 'E', 'e', '→' stand for in dart/flutter docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894436/what-does-t-f-e-e-%e2%86%92-stand-for-in-dart-flutter-docs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <…> notation marks List, Map, Set and other classes as a generic (or parameterized) type — a type that has formal type parameters. By convention, most type variables have single-letter names, such as E, T, S, K, and V.

Please, read [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) carefully.